# Running Scrapy tasks in Python

Tags: python, scrapy

My Scrapy script seems to work just fine when I run it in 'one off' scenarios from the command line, but if I try running the code twice in the same python session I get this error:

"ReactorNotRestartable"

Why?

The offending code (last line throws the error):

```
crawler = CrawlerProcess(settings)
crawler.install()
crawler.configure()

# schedule spider
#crawler.crawl(MySpider())
spider = MySpider()
crawler.queue.append_spider(spider)

# start engine scrapy/twisted
crawler.start()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Close to Joël's answer, but I want to elaborate a bit more than is possible in the comments. If you look at the [Crawler source code](http://dev.scrapy.org/browser/scrapy/crawler.py), you see that the `CrawlerProcess` class has a `start`, but also a `stop` function. This `stop` function takes care of cleaning up the internals of the crawling so that the system ends up in a state from which it can start again.

So, if you want to restart the crawling without leaving your process, call `crawler.stop()` at the appropriate time. Later on, simply call `crawler.start()` again to resume operations.

**Edit:** in retrospect, this is not possible (due to the Twisted reactor, as mentioned in a different answer); the `stop` just takes care of a clean termination. Looking back at my code, I happened to have a wrapper for the Crawler processes. Below you can find some (redacted) code to make it work using Python's multiprocessing module. In this way you can more easily restart crawlers. (Note: I found the code online last month, but I didn't include the source... so if someone knows where it came from, I'll update the credits for the source.)

```
from scrapy import project, signals
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue
from multiprocessing import Process

class CrawlerWorker(Process):
    def __init__(self, spider, results):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.results = results

        self.crawler = CrawlerProcess(settings)
        if not hasattr(project, 'crawler'):
            self.crawler.install()
        self.crawler.configure()

        self.items = []
        self.spider = spider
        dispatcher.connect(self._item_passed, signals.item_passed)

    def _item_passed(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def run(self):
        self.crawler.crawl(self.spider)
        self.crawler.start()
        self.crawler.stop()
        self.results.put(self.items)

# The part below can be called as often as you want
results = Queue()
crawler = CrawlerWorker(MySpider(myArgs), results)
crawler.start()
for item in results.get():
    pass # Do something with item
```

Comment: adding crawler.stop() immediately after crawler.start() didn't help - how do I discover the "appropriate time"?

Comment: @Trindaz: I wasn't correct on that call, please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update @jro. I've seen this snippet before too and, if I've interpreted that correctly, then the concept is you can scrape as much as you want by adding spiders to a crawler that never dies, rather than trying to restart a crawler for every attempt you make at "executing" a spider. I've marked this as a solution because technically it solves my problem but is unusable to me because I don't want to rely to persistent crawler objects in the django application I'm using this in. I ended up writing a solution based purely on BeautifulSoup and urllib2.

Comment: I'd guess you found it here... http://www.tryolabs.com/Blog/2011/09/27/calling-scrapy-python-script/

Comment: Will this still run items through the pipelines defined in the settings?

Comment: hey with this I'm getting error with scrapy.conf, it seems deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

`crawler.start()` starts Twisted reactor. There can be only one reactor.

If you want to run more spiders - use

```
another_spider = MyAnotherSpider()
crawler.queue.append_spider(another_spider)
```

Comment: scrapy 0.14 does not support multiple spiders in a crawlerprocess anymore.

Comment: haven't tested, but this might work (from looking at the source code): `crawler.engine.open_spider(another_spider)`

Comment: why would you want to stop reactor?

Comment: sending a ctrl-c interrupt signal doesn't close the spiders

Comment: yea it did.. but i also ran into some problems with handling the spider_opened and spider_closed signals in my pipeline.. idk, says http://tinyurl.com/cpg55xp that it might need to configure the reactor?

Answer (score 0):

I've used threads to start reactor several time in one app and avoid ReactorNotRestartable error.

Thread(target=process.start).start()

Here is the detailed explanation: [Run a Scrapy spider in a Celery Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116493/run-a-scrapy-spider-in-a-celery-task/36196362#36196362)

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me that you cannot use `crawler.start()` command twice: you may have to re-create it if you want it to run a second time.