# Scrapy spider not following links when using Celery

Tags: python, django, scrapy, twisted, celery

I'm a writing a crawler in Python that crawls all pages in a given domain, as part of a domain-specific search engine . I'am  using Django, Scrapy, and Celery for achieving this. The scenario is as follows:

I receive a domain name from the user and call the `crawl` task inside the view, passing the domain as an argument:

`crawl.delay(domain)`

The task itself just calls a function that starts the crawling process:

```
from .crawler.crawl import run_spider
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def crawl(domain):
    return run_spider(domain)
```

`run_spider` starts the crawling process, [as in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22202877/1802750), replacing `MySpider` with `WebSpider`.

`WebSpider` inherits from `CrawlSpider` and I'm using it now just to test functionality.  The only rule defined takes an `SgmlLinkExtractor` instance and a callback function `parse_page` which simply extracts the response url and the page title, populates a new DjangoItem (`HTMLPageItem`) with them and saves it into the database (not so efficient, I know).

```
from urlparse import urlparse
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from ..items import HTMLPageItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider

class WebSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "web"

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(WebSpider, self).__init__(**kw)
        url = kw.get('domain') or kw.get('url')
        if not (url.startswith('http://') or url.startswith('https://')):
            url = "http://%s/" % url
        self.url = url
        self.allowed_domains = [urlparse(url).hostname.lstrip('www.')]
        self.start_urls = [url]
        self.rules = [
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(
                allow_domains=self.allowed_domains,
                unique=True), callback='parse_page', follow=True)
        ]

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return self.parse_page(response)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = HTMLPageItem()
        item['url'] = response.request.url
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()[0]
        item.save()
        return item
```

**The problem**  is the crawler only crawls the `start_urls` and does not follow links (or call the callback function) when following this scenario and using Celery. However calling `run_spider` through `python manage.py shell` works just fine!

Another problem is that Item Pipelines and logging are not working with Celery. This is making debugging much harder. I think these problems might be related.

Comment: Consider writing a "hello world" program with Celery, and get logging to work. Not seeing what's going on makes things... difficult :)

Comment: Thanks! I got Celery logging working in no time. I was trying to log using Scrapy, and that wasn't working. And logging did help, I fixed the problem :), will post the answer now.

Comment: Pipelines are still not working though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after inspecting Scrapy's code and enabling Celery logging, by inserting these two lines in `web_spider.py`:

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
```

I was able to locate the problem:
In the initialization function of `WebSpider`:

```
super(WebSpider, self).__init__(**kw)
```

The `__init__` function of the parent `CrawlSpider` calls  the [`_compile_rules`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spiders/crawl.py#L76) function which in short copies the rules from `self.rules` to `self._rules` while making some changes. `self._rules` is what the spider uses when it checks for  rules . Calling the initialization function of `CrawlSpider` before defining the rules led to an empty `self._rules`, hence no links were followed.

Moving the `super(WebSpider, self).__init__(**kw)` line to the last line of `WebSpider`'s `__init__` fixed the  problem.

**Update:** There is a little mistake in code from [the previously mentioned SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22202877/1802750). It causes the reactor to hang after second call. The fix is simple, in `WebCrawlerScript`'s `__init__` method, simply move this line:

```
self.crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
```

out of the if statement, as suggested in the comments there.

**Update 2:** I finally got pipelines to work! It was not a Celery problem. I realized that the settings module wasn't being read. It was simply an import problem. To fix it:

Set the environment variable `SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE` in your django project's settings module `myproject/settings.py`:

```
import os
os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.crawler.crawler.settings'
```

In your Scrapy settings module `crawler/settings.py`, add your Scrapy project path to `sys.path` so that relative imports in the settings file would work:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/absolute/path/to/scrapy/project')
```

Change the paths to suit your case.

Comment: Were you using Django Dynamic Scraper or just the normal Scrapy? I'm essentially doing something similar to what you did but I need to use all of the files from my scrapy project within the django project that I've made.