# Celery worker hang when running with twisted

Tags: python-3.x, celery, twisted, reactor, twisted.internet

Below code snippet is the celery setup I have, Here I am running a twisted reactor in each child celery worker process.

```
import os
from threading import Thread
from celery import Celery
from twisted.internet import threads, reactor
from celery import signals
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks, returnValue
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@signals.worker_process_init.connect
def configure_infrastructure(**kwargs):
    thread = Thread(target=reactor.run, name="reactor.run", args=(False,)).start()
    print('STARTED NEW WORKER', os.getpid())

@signals.worker_process_shutdown.connect()
def shutdown_reactor(**kwargs):
    reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)
    print('REACTOR SHUTDOWN', os.getpid())

class OrgUnitEventHandler():
    @inlineCallbacks
    def process(self, *args, **kwargs):
        val = sum(args)
        yield val
        returnValue(val)

def inThread(x, y): 
    obj = OrgUnitEventHandler()
    output = threads.blockingCallFromThread(reactor,
                                        obj.process, x, y)
    return output

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    print('ADD --> '+str(os.getpid()))
    result = inThread(x, y)
    print("FINAL RESULT--> "+str(result)+"-->"+str(os.getpid()))
    return result
```

With the above code, I see most of the time the celery worker got hung and got released when a new task comes on the same worker again. 
see below logs ..

```
[2020-05-07 20:12:26,481: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] STARTED NEW WORKER
[2020-05-07 20:12:26,481: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 11651
[2020-05-07 20:12:26,498: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] STARTED NEW WORKER
[2020-05-07 20:12:26,499: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] 11653
[2020-05-07 20:12:26,515: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] STARTED NEW WORKER
[2020-05-07 20:12:26,515: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] 11655
[2020-05-07 20:12:26,533: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] STARTED NEW WORKER
[2020-05-07 20:12:26,534: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 11659
[2020-05-07 20:12:32,239: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] ADD --> 11651   # task-1 hang
[2020-05-07 20:12:36,611: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] ADD --> 11653   # task-2 hang
[2020-05-07 20:13:00,858: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] ADD --> 11655   # task-3 hang
[2020-05-07 20:13:00,859: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] FINAL RESULT--> 3-->11653  # task-2 Done
[2020-05-07 20:13:00,859: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] FINAL RESULT--> 3-->11655 # task-3 done
```

I never see celery hung issue when I am using `Loopingcall` when running reactor.

```
...


class EventLoop(object):
    def _startLoopingCall(self, reactor):
        lc = LoopingCall(print)
        lc.start(1, False)

    def setup(self, reactor):
        reactor.callFromThread(self._startLoopingCall, reactor)
        thread = Thread(target=lambda: reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False),name="reactor ").start()

@signals.worker_process_init.connect
def configure_infrastructure(**kwargs):
    EventLoop().setup(reactor)
    #thread = Thread(target=reactor.run, name="reactor.run", args=(False,)).start()
    print('STARTED NEW WORKER', os.getpid())

...
```

**Logs to confirm that celery workers never hung with the above code:**

```
[2020-05-07 20:22:08,824: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] STARTED NEW WORKER
[2020-05-07 20:22:08,824: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 12302
[2020-05-07 20:22:08,841: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] STARTED NEW WORKER
[2020-05-07 20:22:08,841: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] 12304
[2020-05-07 20:22:08,857: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] STARTED NEW WORKER
[2020-05-07 20:22:08,857: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] 12306
[2020-05-07 20:22:08,873: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] STARTED NEW WORKER
[2020-05-07 20:22:08,874: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 12308


[2020-05-07 20:22:12,446: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] ADD --> 12302
[2020-05-07 20:22:12,826: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] FINAL RESULT--> 3-->12302
[2020-05-07 20:22:15,489: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] ADD --> 12304
[2020-05-07 20:22:15,842: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] FINAL RESULT--> 3-->12304
[2020-05-07 20:22:17,828: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] ADD --> 12302
[2020-05-07 20:22:17,828: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] FINAL RESULT--> 3-->12302
[2020-05-07 20:22:20,475: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] ADD --> 12304
[2020-05-07 20:22:20,842: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] FINAL RESULT--> 3-->12304
```

**I am not able to figure out what magic LoopingCall is doing here with a twisted reactor to make it work properly. Please share your ideas**

Comment: You should go back to the design board and rethink the approach. Twisted internals do not behave well when run in threads like this. Your implementation would start the reactor in a different thread than the main thread and that just makes this confusing and difficult to debug (as you've now discovered). However, running a **single** Twisted reactor in a thread to do async tasks in the background is doable using [crochet](https://github.com/itamarst/crochet). I think you're basically trying to do this. It's not very clear why you're running Twisted in a thread or why you even need Twisted.

Comment: @notorious.no I see the same behaviour with crochet that it is having a LoopingCall in every 0.1 seconds to reapallprocesses . (https://github.com/itamarst/crochet/blob/master/crochet/_eventloop.py#L367 )  , I am not sure what is the need of making these call here in crochet ?