# Quitting a Python program

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to quit a python program by calling `sys.exit()` but it does not seem to be working.

The program structure is something like:

```
def func2():
    *does some scraping operations using scrapy*

def func1():
    Request(urls, callbakc=func2)
```

So, here, func1 is requesting a list of URLs and the callback method, func2 is being called. I want to quit the execution of the program if something goes wrong in `func2`

On checking the type of the object in `func1` I found its and `http.Request` object.

Also, since I am using `scrapy`, whenever I call `sys.exit()` in `func2`, the next url in the list is called and the program execution continues.

I have also tried to use a global variable to stop the execution but to no avail.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: sys.exit raises a SystemExit exception.  Do you have a naked try: except pass somewhere?

Comment: @zehnpaard no. every `try` has an `except` in my code. Just checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [How can I instruct a spider to stop itself?](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-instruct-a-spider-to-stop-itself), you need to raise [`CloseSpider` exception](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider):

```
raise CloseSpider('Done web-scraping for now')
```

Also see:

- [Running Scrapy tasks in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993680/running-scrapy-tasks-in-python)

`sys.exit()` would not work here since Scrapy is based on `twisted`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if we don't know how to completely stop, Python's [mutable-object default binding "gotcha"](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) can help us skip all callbacks from a certain point on.

Here is what you can do:

First, create a function generating wrapping other callback functions with condition. It's second argument `cont` is going to be bound to a **mutable** object (`list`) so we can affect all callbacks **after** creating them.

```
def callback_gen(f, cont=[True]):
    def c(response):
        if cont[0]:
            f(response, cont=cont)
        else:
            print "skipping" # possibly replace with pass
    return c
```

Now make some testing functions:

```
def func2(response, cont=None):
    print response
    print cont
    # this should prevent any following callback from running
    cont[0]=False

def func3(response, cont=None):
    print response
    print cont
```

And now create two callbacks the first one is `func2` which prevents the following ones from running.

```
f2 = callback_gen(func2)
f3 = callback_gen(func3)
f2("func2")
f3("func3")
```

I like it :)